# MYSQL- High CPU

Tags: mysql

Below are my config values and I'm facing high CPU usage. Please advise the appropriate config values.
My hardware specifications: RAM 32GB; Processer 64 core; OS: Linx

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer=10G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=128M
sort_buffer_size=32M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=32
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64

max_connections=5000
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=512M
table_cache=1024
join_buffer_size=4M
thread_cache_size=128
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256MB
```

Answer (score 0):

`query_cache_size=256M` -- beyond about 50M, bigger means slower.  Lower that.

`key_buffer=10G` -- Are you using `ENGINE=MyISAM`?  In general, you should not.  If you are using MyISAM, lower that to 2G; if not, lower it further, to 30M.

If things are set too high, you run out of RAM; this leads to swapping, which is sloooow for MySQL.

In general, high CPU (or high Load Average) means an inefficient query.  Find that query, then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting setting is meaningless without specifying what storage engine your tables are using.

If you are using MyISAM - you almost certainly shouldn't be.

If you are only using InnoDB, key_buffer_size and myisam_sort_buffer_size are just wasting your memory.

Poor performance is hardly ever about configuration settings. It is almost always about the queries you are running, your table structures and indexes. This is typically a complex task that requires a database optimisation specialist.